# Tables names as reserved keywords in Sqoop

Tags: mysql, sqoop

I have a table `int` in MySQL

```
create table `int` (c1 varchar(20));

insert into `int` values ('some data');
```

I try to import it in hive using Sqoop:

`sqoop import --connect='jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/classicmodels' --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --username xxx --password xxx --table int --delete-target-dir --target-dir /tmp/test --hive-import --hive-table default.test --hive-drop-import-delims --null-string '\\N' --null-non-string '\\N' --split-by col_date -m 1 --verbose`

Internally, it is creating  `SELECT t.* FROM int AS t WHERE 1=0`

Error:

> 16/08/18 13:43:20 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'int AS t WHERE 1=0' at line 1

*which is expected.*

I tried,  `--table "int"`, `` --table `int` `` and  `` --table "`int`" ``.

**None of them worked.**

Is there any way to tell sqoop to create query:

`` SELECT t.* FROM `int` AS t WHERE 1=0 ``

---

`[ ]` is used to bypass reserved words in SQL server.

In SQL Server `--table dbo.[int]` worked  for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide `` --table \`int\` `` .I remember it was working like this.

Comment: it's not able to escape double quotes but I need to escape **`** so it worked. Update your answer

Comment: Thanks for checking

Answer (score 0):

Another way:
Use [Free-form Query Imports](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.7/SqoopUserGuide.html#_free_form_query_imports)

You can use `--query` instead of `--table`:

```sh
sqoop import \
  --query 'SELECT c1 FROM `int` WHERE $CONDITIONS'
  ...
```

And it's especially useful when you have reversed keywords in your columns.